# Status of finite-dimensional Ando's theorem

Tags: oa.operator-algebras, open-problems

[Szőkefalvi-Nagy's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sz.-Nagy%27s_dilation_theorem) says the following: if $A$ is a contraction on a Hilbert space $H$, then there exists a unitary $U$ on a Hilbert space $H'\supset H$ for which $A^n=P_HU^nP_H$ for all $0\le n$. ($P_H$ denotes projection onto $H$.)

If $H$ is finite-dimensional and we only need this to be true for $0\le n\le N$ then this can be modified such that $H'$ is also finite-dimensional (cf. [Levy and Shalit - Dilation theory in finite dimensions: the possible, the impossible and the unknown](https://arxiv.org/abs/1012.4514)).

Ando's theorem (see e.g. Levy–Shalit) says the following: if $A$ and $B$ are commuting contractions on $H$, then there exist commuting unitaries $U$ and $V$ on $H'\supset H$ for which $A^nB^m=P_HU^nV^mP_H$ for all $0\le n,m$.

The construction in the proof is naturally infinite-dimensional even if $H$ is finite-dimensional so a natural question (Problem C in Levy–Shalit) is: if we only need this to be true for $0\le n+m\le N$ then does an analogous modification work to make $H'$ finite-dimensional?

Levy–Shalit make this out to be wide-open, as of 2011. **My question here is if there are any recent developments in the years since then on this or related problems.**

Comment: A small remark: In order to call it an $N$-dilation, one would actually require the dilation equality to be true for all $m,n \ge 0$ that satisfy $m+n \le N$ rather than $m,n \le N$ (see for instance Definition 4.1 in the paper by Levy and Shalit that you linked). I'd say one reason for is that one would like to think of it as substituting $A$ and $B$ into a commutative monomial in two variables where the monomial has degree at most $N$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In their 2013 paper "[Unitary $N$-dilations for tuples of commuting matrices](https://doi.org/10.1090/S0002-9939-2012-11714-9)" McCarthy and Shalit showed that there does indeed exist an $N$-dilation to a finite-dimensional space (see Theorem 1.2 in the paper).

By the way, I found this paper by taking a look at the recent survey article "[Dilation theory: a guided tour](https://zbmath.org/?q=an%3A7393048)" (2021) by Shalit ([link to arXiv](https://arxiv.org/abs/2002.05596)).

Since you're apparently interested in dilation theory, you might also be interested to know that Orr Shalit  has a blog [Noncommutative analysis](https://noncommutativeanalysis.wordpress.com/) where he sometimes writes about dilation theory. For instance, the survey article that I mentioned above is announced in the blog post [A survey (another one!) on dilation theory](https://noncommutativeanalysis.wordpress.com/2020/02/14/a-survey-another-one-on-dilation-theory/).

Comment: Fantastic, this is very helpful! Do you happen to know if there is anything towards a constructive version of McCarthy–Shalit's theorem?

Comment: @zjs: Unfortunately, I don't know whether a constructive proof is known. Maybe you could write to Orr Shalit and ask him? He seems to be one of the very experts on the topic.

Comment: @zjs: If by "constructive" you mean that you write down a pair of commuting m X m matrices, and I write down a finite dimensional commuting pair of unitaries which is the N-dilation for a given N, then as far as I know nobody knows how to do it. The proof in the paper mentioned by Jochen Glueck *is* constructive, at least for strict contractions, but at the end of the process you don't have a formula for the dilation like you do in the one dimensional case. I don't know whether such a formula exists, or whether one can avoid using infinite dimensions (or something similar) in the proof.